# Failure of Fubini's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $X=[1, \infty)$, $Y=[0, 1]$, $\mu=\nu=m$-the Lebesgue measure on $X$ and $Y$ and $\mathcal A=\mathcal B=\mathcal M$-the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $Y$. Show that $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$f(x, y)=e^{-xy}-2e^{-2xy}$$
has finite, but distinct, iterated integrals.

I'm not certain how to actually compute these integrals. I know I need to consider $|f(x,y)| = e^{-xy}+2e^{-2xy}$, which is non-negative, hence, integrable. But how do I show the integral is finite; moreover, how do I go about reversing the order of integration?

Comment: Just compute the iterated integrals. First wrt x then y. Second wrt y then x. It should be a straightforward computation.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. What is the actual computation to be performed?

Comment: Do you know what an iterated integral is?

Comment: $\int_1^\infty dx \int_0^1dy\; f(x,y)$ and $\int_0^1 dy \int_1^\infty dx \; f(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, I do. The issue is that these aren't Riemann integrals, so I can't just find an antiderivative and then evaluate at the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, what do those symbols mean in this context?

Comment: They ARE Riemann integrals. Lebesgue=Riemann when both exist. You do exactly what you said.

Comment: They are iterated (sometimes improper) integrals.  $\int_0^1 dy \; f(x,y)$ has exactly the same value that it does in Calculus 101.   You then want to consider the integral of that with respect to $x$ from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Oh. Okay, then. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like the improper integral doesn't converge, but the problem statement says it should.

Comment: Write what you got when you thought it doesn't converge.